# Unable to set Record Type of Lead object in Salesforce through Segment

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, segment-analytics

Our Salesforce Lead object has multiple Record Types.
Leads are created via Segment.io.
I'm unable to programmatically set what Record Type the Lead is via Segment.

`RecordTypeId` is one of the fields on the Lead object, with a data type of `Record Type`.
I've tried setting `RecordTypeId` to both the `Record Type Name` which is found via `setup -> object manager -> lead -> record types` as well as using the id in the url `lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Lead/RecordTypes/${id}/view`.

One assumption I have is that segment thinks that `RecordTypeId` is a custom field, and it is appending `__c` to the field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoke with the Segment team and they aren't passing `RecordTypeId` to Salesforce calls.  It is on their product roadmap with no ETA.